# css :before doesnt work perfectly in nested divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with css `:before` and `:after`. This is my html:

```
<div id = "test-box">
    1
</div>
```

And this is my css:

```
#test-box:before{
    content: "hello";
}
```

When I run this works perfectly and prints: `hello 1`

But when I put another `div` inside my existing `div`, it doesn't work. This is new html:

```
<div id = "test-box">
    <div>1</div>
</div>
```

In this case, browser prints:

```
hello
1
```

I need hello stay on the left side of 1.

Answer (score 2):

Divs are block elements, so there obviously is a line break when you add the hello **before** the div and the nested div.

When using a nested div, you have to use

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UyVuN/)

```
#test-box div:before{
content: "hello";
}
```

**Update:**
[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UyVuN/1/)

```css
#test-box:before{
content: "hello";
}

#test-box div {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using the [proper language tag to fix that syntax highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: no i have to put "hello" before the main div(test-box) not nested div. this code puts hello before of inner div

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS, if you've got a nested div:

```css
#test-box div:before{
    content: "hello";
}
```

The selector there selects the `div` **in** the element with id `test-box`, and adds the text before that, instead of adding the text before the outer div.

The reason `1` was on a new line was because `divs` are block elements. Your original CSS added the text before the inner `<div>` tag, resulting in a newline after the added text.

So, this happened:

```
<div id="test-box">
    hello
    <div> <!-- the div starting here causes the following text to be displayed on a new line -->
        1
    </div>
</div>
```

And with the modified CSS, this will be the result, instead:

```
<div id="test-box">
    <div>
        hello1
    </div>
</div>
```

---

In case you have to place it in the outer div, add this to your css:

```css
#test-box div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

(keep the other line from your question, also).

This will prevent the inner `div` from wrapping to a a new line.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TZUbK/)**

Comment: no i have to put "hello" before the main div(test-box) not inner div. this code puts hello before of inner div

Comment: @FarhadShirzad: Okay, added a second option to the bottom of the page.

Comment: thanks, this works but my inner div's lost his styles because of display:inner-block;

Comment: @FarhadShirzad: What other styles did you have on it? If you can't use `inline-block`, and you can't place the text before the content of the inner `div`, there's not a lot of options left.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `hello` is on a separate line from `1` is because `1` is wrapped with a block level element (the inner div).

Try this:

```css
#test-box div:before {
  content: "hello";
}
```

Or replace the inner div with a span (or other inline element) if you have control over the HTML.

Comment: I'd suggest using the [proper language tag to fix that syntax highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: no i have to put "hello" before the main div(test-box) not nested div. this code puts hello before of inner div